# Perl LibXML: is it possible to get a return value on Method functions?

Tags: perl, libxml2

I'd like to be able to get some kind of confirmation (e.g. thru setting a boolan variable or by some other means) to confirm each of the following individual method functions were successful rather then to rely exclusively on verification resulting from the toString write method:

```
1.) $node->parentNode->insertAfter($pbc_frag, $node);
2.) $node->unbindNode;
3.) $child->setData ($data);
```

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 4):

Why would they not be successful?

I'd expect them to throw exceptions if they failed.

**Update:** yes, they do...

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::LibXML 2;

my $xml  = XML::LibXML->load_xml(IO => \*DATA);
my $quux = XML::LibXML->new->parse_balanced_chunk('<quux/>');

my ($bar) = $xml->findnodes('//bar');
my ($baz) = $xml->findnodes('//baz');

# $baz isn't within $bar, so cannot insert $quux
# such that $quux is both within $bar and after $baz
$bar->insertAfter($quux, $baz);  # this throws an exception

__DATA__
<foo>
  <bar/>
  <baz/>
</foo>
```

Comment: yes, I agree they would throw an excpetion if they don't work ... it was a stupid thought on my part to even ask the question - I was even going to title the initial question "Stupid Question" lol !!! thanks!